# Remove line breaks "\n" in R

Tags: r, date, line-breaks, type-conversion, factors

I have been trying to remove the line breaks from a data set in R. All the columns are factors hence before i could replace the "\n" with "NA", i need to change the data type from factor to character or Date. I am mentioning my code and a sample data set for a better understanding:

```
     sku          Stockout_start        Stockout_End      create_date
  0BX-164463    \N                 1/29/2015 11:35  1/29/2015 11:35
  0BX-164463    2/11/2015 18:01               \N    2/11/2015 18:01
  0BX-164464    \N                 1/29/2015 11:38  1/29/2015 11:38
  0BX-164464    1/30/2015 4:38                  \N  1/30/2015 4:38
  0BX-164481    \N                 1/28/2015 9:58   1/28/2015 9:58
  0BX-164482    \N                1/29/2015 11:37   1/29/2015 11:37
  0BX-164482    2/4/2015 7:17                 \N    2/4/2015 7:17
  0BX-164483    \N                1/29/2015 11:37   1/29/2015 11:37
  0BX-164483    2/7/2015 4:37                 \N    2/7/2015 4:37
  0BX-164496    \N                1/29/2015 9:45    1/29/2015 9:45
  0BX-164497    \N                1/28/2015 10:02   1/28/2015 10:02
  0BX-164498    \N                1/29/2015 9:45    1/29/2015 9:45
  0BX-164499    \N                1/29/2015 11:36   1/29/2015 11:36
  0BX-164500    \N                1/29/2015 11:36   1/29/2015 11:36
  0BX-164501    \N                1/29/2015 11:36   1/29/2015 11:36
```

I have been using below mentioned codes to correct the data:

```
stk[,2]<- as.Date(as.character(stk[,2]),format = "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
stk[,2]<- as.character(as.Date(stk[,2], origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

But these codes change my column 2 to "NA". 
Kindly help.

Comment: I guess you could specify `na.strings` in the `read.csv/read.table`

Comment: that is not working. I tried. All are factors and while changing the data type it changes entire 2nd column to NA

Comment: Could you show the code you used to read the data.  If you need character columns, specify `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Comment: i have been using this code                                                                           stk <- read.delim("C:/Users/abc/Downloads/stk.xls", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Comment: If you had specified `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, the columns would be character.  Please check `str(stk)`

Comment: I am really confused because for the 3rd column when i use below mentioned code it works: stk[,3]<- as.Date(stk[,3], origin = "1970-01-01")   for 3rd column this code works but for 2nd column it doesn't, which is really strange.

Comment: @AkashSinghi please paste in your question the result of `dput(tail(stk,40))` so that people can use your exact data set. Otherwise you will always be disappointed by the answers.

Comment: @AkashSinghi It did work for me `head(as.Date(stk[,2], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') ,2)#
[1] NA           "2015-02-11"`

Comment: @AkashSinghi You are not specifying the `format` correctly based on the input data showed

Comment: @akrun: Thanks a lot it worked. Now how shall i store the values in my data frame named "stk".                                                                                 I am really new to R. Can you please tell me how to pick this language quickly ?

Comment: @AkashSinghi Did you imply to replace the columns with the `Date` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify `na.strings` and `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `read.csv/read.table`.  (I changed the delimiter to `,` and saved the input data)

```
 stk <- read.csv('Akash.csv', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
       sep=",", na.strings="\\N")
 head(stk,3)
 #         sku  Stockout_start    Stockout_End     create_date
 #1   0BX-164463            <NA> 1/29/2015 11:35 1/29/2015 11:35
 #2   0BX-164463 2/11/2015 18:01            <NA> 2/11/2015 18:01
 #3   0BX-164464            <NA> 1/29/2015 11:38 1/29/2015 11:38
```

If you need to replace multiple columns to "Date" class

```
 stk[-1] <- lapply(stk[-1], as.Date, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') 
 str(stk)
 #'data.frame': 15 obs. of  4 variables:
 #$ sku           : chr  "  0BX-164463" "  0BX-164463" "  0BX-164464" "  0BX-164464" ...
 #$ Stockout_start: Date, format: NA "2015-02-11" ...
 #$ Stockout_End  : Date, format: "2015-01-29" NA ...
 #$ create_date   : Date, format: "2015-01-29" "2015-02-11" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you should indeed clean the data before calling `as.Date`

Can you first make sure your data.frame has stringAsFactors=FALSE, and try

```
stk[stk$Stockout_start=="\N","Stockout_start"]=NA
```

Then your code

```
stk[,2]<- as.Date(as.character(stk[,2]),format = "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
stk[,2]<- as.character(as.Date(stk[,2], origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

Comment: It is not recognising "\N":                                                                       Error: '\N' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\N"

Comment: then please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example before posting a question, and provide a sample data set. Otherwise you will continuously get answers that do not fit your data.

Answer (score 0):

A more simple code is with `strptime`

```
stk[,2]<-strptime(stk[,2], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is simple.  The format is also not correct based on the OP's data.  Also, there are multiple date columns.